# Which pull-up resistors to connect when microSD is interfaced in 1-bit data bus width mode (SDMMC, STM32)?

Tags: stm32, sd

I am going to interface a microSD with STM32H7 (via the SDMMC interface).
The SDMMC supports either 1-bit or 4-bit data bus width.
If I use the 1-bit mode, do I still need the pull-ups on D[3:1] signals or can I use the pull-up only on D0 and CMD signals?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pull-ups are mandatory on all card data pins even if unused.

This is apparent from the simplified SDIO specs available for everyone, and this spec in turn does not specify it directly, but simply refers to the actual physical layer specs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please share some document, from which it's apparent?

Comment: I mentioned the freely available document by name already. It takes 3 seconds to type that into google.

Comment: I can of course google the simplified spec available to anyone, but I would like to know from which chapter or which statement it's apparent that "pull-ups are mandatory on all card data pins even if unused". Your previous answer didn't help much on that. You say:"it's apparent from the simplified SDIO spec" but at the same time "this spec in turn does not specify it directly". This is not helping at all.

Comment: PDF documents can be searched for words like "pull-up" which is how I found it two weeks ago. I don't have the document any more, but the simplified specs can be downloaded for free from SD website after registering, and the real specs where it is directly defined cost money.

Comment: It's 10-100kOhm for the CMD line and DAT lines. If you are using DAT3 for card detection, that pullup needs to be 10-90kOhm. CLK does not need a pullup. Note that in many cases these pullups are already integrated into your host controller, SD voltage translators, or the peripheral, so check your datasheets first!

Comment: ^The above comment is just for people who like me are looking for the required values. For OP, I also couldn't find a reference that you need the pins for 1-bit mode.